# What is Hunk history button in sublime merge

Tags: sublimemerge

In Sublime Merge, while looking at the file history, on hovering the code diff area there appears a `Hunk history` button.

What is the functionality offered with this button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It limits the history to show only the history for those specific lines in that specific file.